# Promql query for per week aggregated data

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I am trying to achieve visualisation of a metric as **"per week data graph**" shown below with prometheus and grafana. The metric returns counter type of data.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOESw.png)

I am getting aggregated view of 4 weeks as below. The query I have used is **sum((sum_over_time((irate(metrics_name[1w]))[4w:1w])) + (sum_over_time((irate(metrics_name[1w]))[4w:1w])))**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3a7E.png)

Can you please help me with the solution to achieve my objective of getting aggregated of per week data.

Comment: If your problem is mere "continuity" of the graph, then set Min step in query options of you panel to `1w`.

Comment: Query you posted doesn't look right, though. If what you want is an aggregate of the increases over the week, you need something like `sum(increase(metric1 [1w])) + sum(increase(metric2 [1w]))`

Comment: What I want to achieve is to get data of the a month visualized as per week data, apparently a bar chart with 4 bars representing data of the weeks

Comment: Then I think you should try what I wrote in my comments. It will do exactly that. Additionally, you might want to tinker a bit with visualization options of a panel, for it to show bars.

Comment: once try this query: 

sum\_over\_time((irate(metrics\_name[1w]))[4w:1w]



and provide a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @KapilSakhare, your query is its giving the aggregated of 3 weeks value and not the individual bar charts for each week use please find below screenshot

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3lOA.png

Comment: Hi @markalex, below is the screenshot for your query result, but it still does not fulfill the objective [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/74BLg.png

Comment: It doesn't look like you applied recommended `Min step` option.